# How can I combine data from 4 mysql tables

Tags: mysql, excel, database, csv

I have 4 mysql tables that contain data. Every table has the same columns and names and types and everything , only the data changes. Each table has different number of records as every table represent a different year. So a table for 2015,2016,2017 and 2018. The tables have data about companies and the money they owe to a government service. So every table have mostly the same data with a few changes (some companies paid). I want to create a fifth table that combine these tables with extra columns etc. table for 2015 has a column for the amount owned and a column for a bank payment code, same for the other table, I want in the fifth table to have columns for all years for amount any payment codes, the rest stays the same .
How do i do something like that?
Thank you.

```
    CREATE TABLE `2015` (
  `id2015` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `eponymia` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `afm` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gemi` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nomiki_morfi` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `payment_code` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `chamber_reg` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tmima` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dimos` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `street` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `number` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tk` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mobile` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fax` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id2015`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=7735 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

this is the schema for one of the tables, the others are identical
and the schema for the table i want to fill is this

```
CREATE TABLE `all_years` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `eponymia` varchar(240) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount_2015` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount_2016` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount_2017` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount_2018` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `kodikos_2015` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `kodikos_2016` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `kodikos_2017` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `kodikos_2018` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dimos` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `street` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `number` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tk` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `all_years_id_uindex` (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1686615 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I want the column "amount_2015" and "kodikos_2015" to contain the data from the 2015 table and so on. 
this is an example of data

```
81  "company name"  020587798   2036001000  ΑΤΟΜΙΚΗ Ενεργή  30.00   00200000196546264229    "VAT"   Εμπορικό    ΚΥΠΑΡΙΣΣΙΑΣ / ΜΕΣΣΗΝΙΑΣ ΚΥΠΑΡΙΣΣΙΑ  ΑΡΜΕΝΙΟΙ        24500   2761024466          
82  "company name"  129915690   14689845000 ΑΤΟΜΙΚΗ Ενεργή  30.00   00200000100549364229    "VAT"   Υπηρεσιών   ΛΕΥΚΤΡΟΥ / ΜΕΣΣΗΝΙΑΣ    ΠΥΡΓΟΣ ΛΕΥΚΤΡΟΥ         24024               
83  "company name"  302641263   14690945000 ΑΤΟΜΙΚΗ Ενεργή  30.00   00200000212785864222    "VAT"   Επαγγελματιών   ΦΙΛΙΑΤΡΩΝ / ΜΕΣΣΗΝΙΑΣ   ΦΙΛΙΑΤΡΑ    ΚΕΝΤΡΙΚΗ ΠΛΑΤΕΙΑ        24300               
84  "company name"  800171859   14691745000 ΕΕ  Λύση - Εκκαθάριση   80.00   00200000212787664228    "VAT"   Εμπορικό    ΑΥΛΩΝΑ / ΜΕΣΣΗΝΙΑΣ  ΚΥΠΑΡΙΣΣΙΑ  1 ΧΙΛ ΚΑΛΟΥ ΝΕΡΟΥ - ΤΣΑΚΩΝΑΣ    0   24500               
85  "company name"  110084982   14692445000 ΑΤΟΜΙΚΗ Ενεργή  30.00   00200000212789664228    "VAT"   Μεταποιητικό    ΦΙΛΙΑΤΡΩΝ / ΜΕΣΣΗΝΙΑΣ   ΦΙΛΙΑΤΡΑ            24300
```

Also i am not exactly sure how this site works so if i do something stupid give me little time and i will fix it.

Comment: You should provide the schema of your tables, and a minimal example of data (don't have to be real data values), but I guess [UNION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html) can be an option for this.

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for `UNION ALL`.

Try something like this.

```
    SELECT 2015 AS year, company, owed, payment, paymentcode FROM tbl2015
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2014 AS year, company, owed, 0 AS payment, '' AS paymentcode FROM tbl2014
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2013 AS year, company, owed, 0 payment, '' paymentcode FROM tbl2013
```

When you use `UNION ALL` or `UNION` each of the resultsets in the union must have the same number of columns. I wrote `... 0 AS payment, '' AS paymentcode  ...` to put fake columns in the unioned result set where the table doesn't have those columns in it.